# Is it appropriate to ask for a raise after 1 year?

Tags: salary, performance-reviews, raise

I recently accepted a job at a company after my wife and I were relocated for her job. We moved to a border town where most of the employees are H1B Visa's. During the time of the move I was notified my current employer was shutting down, and so I went on a scramble to find a job. The area I am in has virtually no competition in the world IT and so choices are fairly limited.

I have 3+ years experience in the field I am currently in, and with this additional year will make it 4. I accepted an offer for 40K as this was the highest they were able to offer. My previous position I was pulling in approximately 65K, so it was a huge hit to the old pocket book.

I have now been with this company about a year and do significantly more work and more complex work than others under the same title. An example; A co-worker spent 3 months writing a single script to do some fairly menial tasks that was his primary job (automated his job). I have written 6 scripts that are quite a bit more complex, been set as the backup for deployments, deploy applications, and have taken an idea from concept to implementation while mentoring another developer who was unfamiliar with the framework. I have also been assigned work that Dev III's were assigned and didn't have the time to finish. I received recognition from my project manager through the company's recognition tool with-in the first 6 months of being on the team.

Is it viable to ask for a raise during the 1-year performance review? If not, why? If so, is asking for a 25K raise too much? I have looked on various websites (including [Bureau of Labor and Statistics](http://www.bls.gov)) and found that I am in the lowest 10% of people in the same/similar role. I have also looked on Glassdoor for my exact job title under the company I am employed with, and I am easily making 1/2 of what other employees in the same role are making.

Comment: A request for a 50%+ raise may get you laughed out of the office if you are staying in the same position.  You've already proven your technical chops, best prospects for getting a raise over 10% are in angling for a promotion.

Comment: The concern with my current income is that if I am unable to move from the current location, is that this base salary is going to set the trend for all future raises and promotions. Which means, if Person A gets hired at 55K and I am hired at 40K, a 4% raise for the 55K is 2200, where for 40K it's 1600.

Comment: That's why I'm saying angle for a promotion.  You probably get into a different payscale that isn't based on present wage + X%.

Comment: @Myles +1, can't up vote here yet.

Comment: Personally I think it is a weak argument to state that your work is "better" than someone else so you should get a pay raise. In the eyes of upper management, you both produced equal work unless you can prove your work brought them more money. Even then you only negotiated your base salary and they'll go off that to determine your pay raise, if any.

Comment: Don't believe I ever stated my work is "better" @Dan. Just stated that I do significantly more work than my counterparts.

Comment: Perhaps you should look for a new job elsewhere.  You are in a much better bargaining position than when you were scrambling.  If you made 65K before, you should be able to find a position that pays that (or more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking for over 50% is probably a bit much, unless you are not just doing 50% more, but can show that you are earning them more. I had a job with a raise this big after a year, precisely because my hours which were actually getting billed to clients and therefore easy to see revenue was three times more than others.

It's harder to show the concrete worth of internal work to an accountant type person. Although they're easy enough to understand if you're actually know the tech. In that case the best person to convince is your manager and let them negotiate for you.

If the job market is an employers market in that area, then I would think you are out of luck. You don't have enough leverage. You would be the best judge of that angle.

Probably a good idea to job search a bit and see if you can get a position with a higher salary, at the very least it would be a 'real' bargaining chip rather than theory. Personally though if I found a position that paid 50% more, I'd take it, rather than try and use it to get a pay rise where I was.

> Is it appropriate to ask for a raise after a year?

I wouldn't want to work anywhere that didn't give me a raise every year, so if they don't give it off their own volition, then it's entirely appropriate to push for one.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for a raise after 1 year is pretty normal.  How much can you ask for?  Really this comes down to two factors.

- how much is the highest paid person in your position make?  And are you as good or better than them?  And this is more than just writing scripts but your overall employee package - which communication and self management come into play.
- how much would it cost to replace you - not your job title?  This is fairly easy to figure.  Go on some interviews at a couple other companies and see what they offer you.  In fact if you are making that much less than what you deserve then you may have to do this.  It is sad but most companies are only willing to negotiate this much if you already have another offer in hand.  But be willing to work for this other company as losing cheap labor can spark hostility.  So your expectations should be get an offer for 65k at another company, take that to current company and tell them that you would rather stay... they will either try to match because they don't want to lose you or very well could have you grab your personal belongings before you go.